# How to conditionally run useSubscription hook of Apollo client?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, apollo

Is there anyone who tried with conditional call of `useSubscription`? I want to call `useSubscription` right after `useLazyQuery` is completed. For example, when I populate a data table, subscription should be invoked right after data fetched by `useLazyQuery` is shown on the table. So that the table stays updated. `useLazyQuery` is called when the component is mounted. Please share your solution with me if you have. Thanks!

Comment: use skip option

Comment: Thank you, @xadm

Comment: @DennisWang Did you solve this? Am struck with same kind of issue here

Comment: @xadm dennisWang https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67710167/call-usesubscription-after-a-button-click-or-after-a-variable-update can you answer my question

Comment: The skip option is not in the documentation, though it works fine with useSubscription(),  thank you @xadm !